# how to manage more then one request at a same time to the database?

Tags: sql-server, database

Having a db table "uniqueID" from where i am generating unique id for any user who comes to 
register. At a time in table it has got only one unique id, which is given to a any registrar 
when he comes to register, and for second user i have mechanism through which it increase 
the id value and put it in Db table, but i am afraid if at the same time two user comes to 
register then how should i manage to allot the ID to more then one user, how should i make it work,
is there any internal mechanism which handle it? OR i need to make some different concept.

Comment: basically what my Sp does it returns ID on first come first server basis, but what if more than one user make request to stored procedure at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using an [`IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) constraint on your ID field and return the newly generated ID using [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx).

Comment: How will it help me if two request comes at the same time?

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: it will help you because the database is smart enough not to assign the same ID twice.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet - part of the responsibilities of a database is handling of concurrency. In the case of an `IDENTITY` constraint, this means no two records will get the same ID.

Comment: If request come at the same time then? how will it decide who to send id at first?

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet - Good question. It will pick one. I don't know the exact algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of your application deciding the uniqueID, you should set the column in your user table to have the identity-property, and then let SQL Server return this value back to the application using the function scope_identity().

Comment: Do scope identity handles one request at a time, and put second in pool, if two request comes at the same time?

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: Short answer is: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using a universally unique identifier ([UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)) instead of an increasing id. As an UUID is practically unique you won't have any problems with collisions.

Comment: I never said I would cluster an index on UUID